# How to get the first five values once using a regular expression in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, regex

I am trying to return the first five checkpoint values from my object. I firstly, get all keys that contain checkpoint, testing against a regular expression. I am getting the wrong values and I know its because of the regex but not sure how to fix it. It seems to be getting to checkpoint5 then skipping to checkpoint10

```
var data = {
  practicals: '0',
  checkpoint1: '1',
  checkpoint2: '1',
  checkpoint3: '1',
  checkpoint4: '0',
  checkpoint5: '0',
  checkpoint6: '0',
  checkpoint7: '0',
  checkpoint8: '0',
  checkpoint9: '0',
  checkpoint10: '1',
  checkpoint11: '0',
  checkpoint12: '0',
  total: '2' 
}

var res = Object.keys(data)
  .filter(value => /^checkpoint([1-5])\d*/i.test(value))
  .map(e => data[e])

console.log(res)

// Current output: ["1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0"]

// Expected output: ["1", "1", "1", "0", "0"]
```

Comment: Property names do not necessarily have an order and your regex matches `checkpoint10` and `checkpoint11` and `checkpoint12` too.  Just look at `Object.keys(data)` to see.

Comment: Why is your expected output `["1", "1", "1", "0", "0"]` when checkpoints 1 to 5 are respectively `["1", "0", "0", "0", "0"]`?

Comment: @Nikhil Sorry, I have just edited it

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry, I don't understand what you are meaning

Comment: You need `/^checkpoint[1-5]$/i`

Comment: This just looks like the wrong way to solve a problem  because properties can be in any order, they are not meant for ordered data.  You could sort the prop names if you really need the 5 with the lowest numbers in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple adjustment fixes it.

```js
var data = {
  practicals: '0',
  checkpoint1: '1',
  checkpoint2: '1',
  checkpoint3: '1',
  checkpoint4: '0',
  checkpoint5: '0',
  checkpoint6: '0',
  checkpoint7: '0',
  checkpoint8: '0',
  checkpoint9: '0',
  checkpoint10: '1',
  checkpoint11: '0',
  checkpoint12: '0',
  total: '2' 
}

var res = Object.keys(data)
  .filter(value => /^checkpoint([1-5])$/i.test(value))
  .map(e => data[e])

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `/^checkpoint([1-5])$/i`. `\d*` is causing matching on any checkpoint greater than 9, and you don't need it.